# Insert into MySQL from array with mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I want to insert some data from a parsed JSON to a table, but when I do it, it doesn't work, it returns 0 rows, what am I missing? I'm new yet with this "mysqli". I have more than 25000 rows to insert to the table.

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', '');

$allData = $dataSource->getAllData();
foreach ($allData as $key => $value) {
    $query = 'INSERT INTO `table`(`data_id`, `name`) VALUES (' . $value['data_id'] . ', ' . $value['name'] . ')';
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
}
```

Comment: What returns zero rows? I don't see any code that does that here. There's also a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: i use phpmyadmin and when i want to open the table it returns 0 rows i didn't get there in the code yet, i'll do it after i can solve this :D

Comment: sry forgot to post that, but it is in the code, i don't get errors, i think the problem is in the VALUES i want to insert, $value['data_id'] for example

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Seems like you should set single quotes around your data values. Also adding a [`mysqli_error`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) check for your [`mysqli_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) line so you can actually see what is happening:

```
$allData = $dataSource->getAllData();
foreach ($allData as $key => $value) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `table`(`data_id`, `name`) VALUES ('" . $value['data_id'] . "', '" . $value['name'] . "')";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
}
```

Or better yet, use [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) like this. Allow MySQLi to deal with the whole query data structuring instead of having to worry about single quote placement. Also, added a check for [`mysqli_connect_error`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php) on your [`mysqli_connect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) line:

```
// Connecting, selecting database
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', '') or die(mysqli_connect_error());

$allData = $dataSource->getAllData();
foreach ($allData as $key => $value) {
    // Set the query.
    $query = "INSERT INTO `table`(`data_id`, `name`) VALUES (?, ?)";
    
    // Bind the params.
    // mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 'ss', $value['data_id'], $value['name']);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 'is', $value['data_id'], $value['name']);

    // Run the query.
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
}
```

Note that I have a commented line for the [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) since it’s not clear to me if your `$value['data_id']` is a number or a string. The  `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 'is',…` means the first value is an integer (`i`) and the next value is a string (`s`). Feel free to adjust to best fit your actual data types.

Answer (score 2):

You should use prepared statements. Using parameter binding is not only safer (no SQL injections), but it also a little bit faster when you add 25000 rows.

Your fixed code with error reporting and prepared statements would look like this:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbname');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');

$allData = $dataSource->getAllData();

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO `table`(`data_id`, `name`) VALUES (?,?)');

foreach ($allData as $key => $value) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $value['data_id'], $value['name']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```