# Insert multiple values from API into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am connected to an API that keeps track of customer orders.  Some orders have one product but some orders have multiple products in one order.  When I try and INSERT into my database I only get the first product.  I would like to have all the products inserted in the cases where their are more than one.  The API's XML to the productName is ->orderItems->orderItem->productName and I am trying to loop through all of them but I still only get the first product.

```
foreach ($customer_orders as $customer_order) {
    $chOrder = curl_init('https://' . $customer_order->reference);
    curl_setopt($chOrder, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username" . ":" . "password");
    curl_setopt($chOrder, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));
    curl_setopt($chOrder, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $orderResult = curl_exec($chOrder);
    curl_close($chOrder);

    $shouldContinue = true;
    try {
        $singleXML = new SimpleXMLElement($orderResult);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $shouldContinue = false;
        error_log($e);
        error_log('Failed to get history for ' . wp_get_current_user()->user_email . ' using refernece: ' .  $customer_order->reference);
    }

    if ($shouldContinue) {

        ++$orderCount;


        foreach ($singleXML->orderItems->orderItem as $item) {
            $product = htmlentities($item->productName, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        }


        $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'database');

        $query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO customer_product_list(`product`)VALUES('$product')";

        mysqli_query($con, $query);

        mysqli_close($con);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert into MySQL from array with mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333301/insert-into-mysql-from-array-with-mysqli)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try put insert query inside foreach loop

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','database');
foreach ( $singleXML->orderItems->orderItem as $item ) {
    $product = htmlentities($item->productName, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO customer_product_list(`product`) VALUES('$product')";

    mysqli_query($con,$query);     
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: actualy for each time product is replaced with the new one and finally last oroduct will be inserted into db

Comment: So how can I get all of them in there?

Comment: as i answered try put insert query inside foreach loop and place conn before outside the loop

Comment: I appreciate the help but I tried it and it still only inserts the first one.

Comment: then first print ($product) and see how many products are printing inside foreach loop

Comment: and why are u using ignore in query?in order to use ignore u have to make product column unique to prevent errors on duplications

Comment: I have others columns that I am using to be unique.  I have no problems with my other columns just the product column.  When I echo out my products from an order it still only shows the first product and doesn't show the others.  Im not too sure why.  Im going to contact the API and see what support says.

Comment: then obviously when there is one product then there will be one insertion

Comment: I contacted the API and it was an issue on their end.  The code you gave me was correct.